# Set empy view on ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listfragment, empty-list

I've got a list fragment with a custom adapter, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    CustomArrayAdapter adapt = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), DummyContent.ITEMS);
    setListAdapter(adapt);
}
```

The problem is that I want to set a view in case of no items in my list. How I could do it? My java class is extending ListFragment. Thank you!

Comment: The complete class file is here: 
https://github.com/Ibbus93/IUM/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/valarmorghulis/unica/it/uniapp/carriera/EsameListFragment.java

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom layout in your ListFragment then you can just create a view inside your xml file with this id[(layout taken from the docs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="8dp"
         android:paddingRight="8dp">

     <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#00FF00"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

     <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:background="#FF0000"
               android:text="No data"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

There is also a helper method in ListFragment called [setEmptyText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setEmptyText(java.lang.CharSequence)) that will display the text when your listview is empty.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't really understand. My layout resource is this:
https://github.com/Ibbus93/IUM/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_esame_list.xml
How can I update it for setEmptyText?

Comment: If you are just going to use a TextView just call the method setEmptyText("No Data") in you ListFragment

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved my problem in other way. In the class "EsameListActivity":

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // If there are items in the list
    if(DummyContent.ITEMS.size() != 0)
        // Show the lsit
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_esame_list); 
    else
        // Show a view with a message error
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_empty_list);
 }
```

So it solves my problem!